# How can i change the content a table tag in html with values retrieved from database upon filtering it with buttons

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the data fetched by mysql in a table tag when a button is click. It's like filtering the data in the table by active and inactive

Comment: What did you have tried yet?

Comment: i tried using ajax call . the requested php file passed something like this "<td>$name</td>" , btw im using a while loop in the requested php

Comment: i guess it doesnt work because of the while loop . what is the proper way to do it

Comment: Its difficult to understanf it without code...

Comment: okay i get the idea of your answer. ill just try if it works in my code thanks ^^

Comment: How about if my filter is a select tag in html ?

Comment: What do you mean? Your filter is an html id or class? Ah ok saw your answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "can I haz teh codez" question

Comment: I just want to have an idea on how to do this. You can answer like "You have to use ajax for that" or "Use get method to make it happen". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
How about this:

<form method=POST>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" name=filter onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You could post the form the same way as in my solution. Use method="get" and change my "age" to the id of your select field

Comment: thanks it works fine , great ^^

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, it is a comment on another post.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a get request and pass a value to it to filter:

```
<?php
$age=""
if(isset($_GET["age"])){
$age=htmlspecialchars($_GET["age"]);
}
$query="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE age='$age'";
//run query + output
?>
```

Use this link to filter

```
<a href="?age=18">Just show 18 year old</a>
```

Or this form:

```
<form action="thissite.php" method="get">
<select name="age" id="age">
<option value="18">18</option>
...
</select>
<button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```